# Fundamental problem - Word frequencies/histogram in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, nlp, histogram, word-frequency

I've spent an entire day on this and I cannot seem to find my mistake. I'm sure someone else will be able to spot it in a second (for which I am thankful).

I have a few text files that I need to analyze; it doesn't matter what's in them (use lorem ipsum for a reproducible example). I am at the EDA step. My code looks like this:

```
lorem <- readLines("lorem.txt", skipNul = TRUE) # Read in data; this works

# stringi functions
library(stringi)

# Count words in each entry; this also works fine
lorem_wc <- data.frame(stri_count_words(lorem))
```

This produces a data frame with one column with the number of words in each line - so far, this works great. Now I'd like to create a histogram (i.e., see a distribution of word-count frequencies); the number of words would be on the horizontal axis and the frequency of each would be on the vertical. My thought was this:

```
lorem_df <- table(lorem_wc)
```

This produces something I don't want (I'm not actually sure what this is, but it's clearly not what I want - it's a single row of information, but I don't understand what R computed. If I try this:

```
lorem_df <- data.frame(table(stri_count_words(lorem)))
```

I get the same information, but it's now in a column instead of a row. The contents are still not what I'd expect. So I created a test file and did the same thing:

```
testfile <- readLines("test.txt", skipNul = TRUE)
testtab <- data.frame(table(stri_count_words(testfile)))
```

When I print `testtab`, it looks like a two-column data frame; the first column is called `Var1` and looks like it's the number of words per line in the text file called "test.txt". The second column is called `Freq` and looks like it's the frequency that goes with the number of words in the first column.

Now I use ggplot to generate a histogram:

```
g <- ggplot(testtab, aes(x = Var1))
g <- g + geom_histogram()
g
```

... which throws an error: `Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable: the x variable is discrete. Perhaps you want stat="count"?`

I'm sure this is trivial, but I've apparently gone into vapor lock.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the output from str(testtab)?

Comment: Try adding `%>% as.numeric()` like this: `ggplot(testtab, aes(x = Var1 %>% as.numeric()))`

Comment: @ Bill - I think you and @Kat were on the right track. Here's the output:

str(testtab)
'data.frame': 7 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Var1: Factor w/ 7 levels "1","3","4","5",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
 $ Freq: int  1 2 2 1 1 1 1

Comment: The problem with using `testtab` is that `Var1` is changed to a factor when `table()` is pulled into the `data.frame`. Kat's comment supplies one way to deal with wrong type.

Comment: If it's a factor, you have to change it to a `character()` first! `ggplot(testtab, aes(x = Var1 %>% as.character() %>% as.numeric()))` It will change all of your values if you don't.

Comment: @Kat - Now I understand - thank you! Why does R do this? It seems ... counterintuitive to me.

Comment: Not sure on that one. Have to find the R fantabulous for that answer!